# Mouse lags in Draftsight for Ubuntu 64 Bit 14.04

Tags: nvidia, mouse

Mouse lags in Draftsight 2015 SP2, Ubuntu 14.04, Video Card Nvidia Quadro 600, Nvidia driver version 340.76

SuperMicro X9-SCA series board, Intel E3-1230 Processor, 8 Gig memory.

Answer (score 2):

The OP managed to fix the problem themselves, as [posted in the original question:](https://askubuntu.com/posts/625433/revisions)

> Go to Nvidia X server settings; OpenGL Settings; and uncheck Sync to VBlank. Reboot, this fixed my mouse problem in Draftsight. -tfsron

Answer (score 1):

I had this also - Draftsight 2015 SP3, 64bit.
I'm sure the previous post about sync to vblock is valid.
For others, the problem is related to the speed of your pc graphics.
Separate card or integrated - it still graphics speed.
Here's why.
I use Ubuntu 14.04 on several different PCs.
E8400, 3 GHz, GMA4500 integrated graphics, Passmark 68 - lag is there.
   Not suitable for Draftsight, Wolfdale is before Sandy Bridge.
Same PC with NVidia FX370 PCIe card, Passmark 91-100, lag is better.
   Still not suitable for Draftsight.
G2120, Ivy Bridge 3 GHz, Intel HD graphics, Passmark +- 400, works fine.
   These have only 6 EUs, but it appears what each EU is able to do is key
Mini PC, Celeron 2957U, 1.5GHz, Intel HD graphics, Passmark +- 400, fine.

So you see - the CPU speed is not the factor.
A 2 core 2 thread Haswell Celeron at 1.5 GHz, 4GB RAM, 12EUs is ok
The speed of the graphics is the key.
This shows Intel has come a long way in improving their graphics for 2D.
I think a Passmark score of +- 400 results in no lag.
So if you have the lag, you need faster graphics, not a faster CPU.
Hope this helps - my 2 cents.

Comment: But how does this help the OP? I doubt they want to upgrade their video card.

Comment: I use touchpad and it lags. When I plug in the mouse it works fine. It can't be the speed of the graphics card because I didn't change my graphic card.

Using a empty new file, touchpad works fine. Using 5MB dwg file, it lags. Plug in the mouse 5MB file does not lag. ?!

Answer (score 0):

I tried every solution and nothing worked.

I managed to downgrade back to SP1.

For the ones that want to do that.

http://dl-ak.solidworks.com/nonsecure/draftsight/V1R6.1/draftSight.deb

Answer (score 0):

I just loaded Draftsight 2016 for Ubuntu and it has cured the mouse lag problem and on test is working well opening 8MB files.